# CSS is not working for table td

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using ASP.NET which uses all default javascript libraries like Bootstrap, jQuery and ...

I'm ty\rying to customize the EDIT View, generated by Visual Studio. I want to apply a style for table cells but my css is not working and the dropdown is not vertically in the middle

I tried following CSS, but none of them worked

```
<style type="text/css">
    #tb_dataentry td {
        vertical-align: auto;
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    td {
        vertical-align: auto;
    }
</style>
```

`#tb_dataentry` is the id of my table.

I also used `middle` instead of `auto` and used `!important` word but no luck.

If I use the same style for each individual TD, it works, but I want to do that in one place.

This is the html of my table

```
<table id="tb_dataentry">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:auto">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.PropertyType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Edit: Compiled HTML

```
...... many things above this line
<style type="text/css">
    td {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>

<!-- Start page content -->
<section id="page-content" class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="about-sheltek-area ptb-115">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <form action="/ManageProperties/Edit/1" method="post">
                    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="3_tLe9pLOu0CiWg8X81ivfdT0rjyvb4XnCIyAeR0k8uoP8FE_3hMA3xtZh2igj_9Q3SMGBb5WxdxEkNeNkZrTP-WeGpGugHOKVZ7Zxa_8n81" />
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <h4>Property</h4>
                        <hr />

                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PropertyId must be a number." data-val-required="The PropertyId field is required." id="PropertyId" name="PropertyId" type="hidden" value="1" />

                        <table id="tb_dataentry">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="PropertyType">PropertyType</label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PropertyType field is required." id="PropertyType" name="PropertyType">
                                                <option value="0">Apartment</option>
                                                <option selected="selected" value="1">Condo</option>
                                                <option value="2">SingleFamily</option>
                                                <option value="3">MultiFamity</option>
                                                <option value="4">Villa</option>
                                                <option value="5">Suite</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="PropertyType" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>
                                        </div>
```

[image: See the HTML Image]

Comment: so is there another CSS rule that is overriding what you are setting?

Comment: probably. that's why I used !important. but if that's the case it should not works when I use the style in TD tag.

Comment: [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) .... inspect the element and see what is overriding your style. Make a rule that has a higher specificity.

Comment: Which `td` is not styling correctly, the first or the second (containing the `div`'s)?

Comment: I inspected and I don't see anything the may affect this

Comment: @MarcAudet, the first one which is a label. the edit box is in the middle already

Comment: added image and compiled html

Comment: Correction, the label is OK but the drop down is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto` is not valid value for `vertical-align` property. default value is `initial`

you can see valid values here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

for your case alignment could be done by editing `.form-group` behavior - it should have `inline-block` display mode, in this case `vertical-align` property can handle its behavior

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
#tb_dataentry td {
    vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.control-label {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
      margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
</style>

<!-- Start page content -->
<section id="page-content" class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="about-sheltek-area ptb-115">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <form action="/ManageProperties/Edit/1" method="post">
          <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="3_tLe9pLOu0CiWg8X81ivfdT0rjyvb4XnCIyAeR0k8uoP8FE_3hMA3xtZh2igj_9Q3SMGBb5WxdxEkNeNkZrTP-WeGpGugHOKVZ7Zxa_8n81" />
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Property</h4>
            <hr />

            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PropertyId must be a number." data-val-required="The PropertyId field is required." id="PropertyId" name="PropertyId" type="hidden" value="1" />

            <table id="tb_dataentry">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="PropertyType">PropertyType</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PropertyType field is required." id="PropertyType" name="PropertyType">
                        <option value="0">Apartment</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="1">Condo</option>
                        <option value="2">SingleFamily</option>
                        <option value="3">MultiFamity</option>
                        <option value="4">Villa</option>
                        <option value="5">Suite</option>
                      </select>
                      <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="PropertyType" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: I already have tried middle as I mentioned. what else should I try. BTW, this is not the answer, please put it in comment

Comment: can you provide compiled html please?

Comment: added image and html

Comment: You are right about the .form-group. I removed it and it worked. but when I use your CSS, it is still not aligned. however your snippet works correctly. Weird!. Have you changed anything in HTML? or I can fix it by only using the css?

Comment: @FLICKER I edited the snippet so it has all css in `<style>` tag now, make sure it goes after you include `bootsrap.css`. which version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: I already put it inside <style> tag. in my page, I have bootstrap.css on top and then my css. bootstrap.js is on bottom of page. do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: If I add margin-top: 10px !important; to .form-group, it will display correctly, I don't like that solution though. if you can figure it out would be great otherwise I go with 10px.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131820/discussion-between-godblessstrawberry-and-flicker).

Comment: we ended up with the style specified in answer. Thank you sir!